# Create an image in WPF whose pixels are randomly chosen

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create an 800x600 image whose each pixel is randomly chosen to be either green or red. How can I do this in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx)

```
const uint red = 0xFFFF0000,green = 0xFF00FF00;
var rnd = new Random();
var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(800, 600, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);
var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 800 * 600).Select(x => rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5 ? red : green).ToArray();
bmp.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 800, 600), data, bmp.BackBufferStride, 0);
```

That is a simple example and does not cover dealing with the bitmap stride, different pixel formats or alpha.

Comment: awesome. just what i needed.